# Difference between COUNTIF(range,"*") and {SUM(ISTEXT(range)*1)}

Tags: excel

I just learned about using wildcards in Excel functions like `COUNTIF()`, and I wondered whether there is any circumstance under which the following two formulas would give different results:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B10,"*")
{=SUM(ISTEXT(B1:B10)*1)}
```

The objective is to count the number of text (non-numeric) values in the range.

In the following example, B3 is the formulta `=MID("abc",3,1)` and B9 is the formula `=SUM(1,2)`, so I know it works for formulas that return text or numeric values. But is there any odd type of cell content that would cause `COUNTIF()` and the `SUM` array formula to give different counts?

[image: Example]

Comment: Nope. Both should always output the exact same count. `COUNTIF` will just be faster then the array formula.

Comment: Thanks, @DirkReichel!

Comment: @DirkReichel Kindly share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. | Alternatively, the question owner may do so too.. (: